# Python 3.10 script calling a Powershell script - How to store output after a certain string

Tags: python, powershell

I am hoping someone can help me with this issue as I am lost.
I am calling a Powershell script that produces several lines of output, this in an extract:

```
7-Zip 22.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2022 Igor Pavlov : 2022-07-15

Scanning the drive:
7 folders, 21 files, 21544 bytes (22 KiB)

Creating archive: conf.tar
Creating archive: conf2.tar

Removing tar file after upload...
Generating Links:
--------------------------------------------------------------
Link_1
https://some-repository.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/conf.tar?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
--------------------------------------------------------------
Link_2
https://some-repository.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/conf2.tar?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
```

My Python script calls the Powershell script this way:

```
import subprocess, sys
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
              "script.ps1"], 
              stdout=sys.stdout, shell=True)              
p_out, p_err = p.communicate()
print(p_out)
```

And I can see the output on screen when I run the python script from a Powershell CLI.
Is there a way to extract those links from the output and pass them to Python?

Comment: you should have all in `p_out` as string (so you already have it in Python) and now you should use Python's functions to extract it from this string. You can split to lines and search line with `https` at the beginning. OR you can use regex.

Comment: @furas, the problem is `stdout=sys.stdout` (rather than `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`), which prevents `p_out` from receiving any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In order to *capture* stdout and stderr output, you must replace `stdout=sys.stdout` with `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE`.

  - By contrast, `stdout=sys.stdout` passes output from the PowerShell call directly through to the console (terminal), so `p_out` and `p_err` ended up as `None`.
- There is no need for `shell=True` (calling via the platform's default shell) in your case - it only slows things down.
- Adding `universal_newlines=True` makes Python automatically report the collected stdout and stderr output as *strings*; in v3.7+, you can use the conceptually clearer alias `text=True`
- While you could extract the lines of interest in Python code *afterwards*, a small addition to your PowerShell call allows you to do that at the source.

Therefore:

```py
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
  ['powershell', '-NoProfile', '-Command', "(./script.ps1) -match '^https://'" ], 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True
)

# Wait for the process to terminate and collect its stdout and stderr output.
p_out, p_err = p.communicate()

# Split the single multi-line string that contains the links
# into individual lines.
lines = p_out.splitlines()

print(lines)
```

Note:

- PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameters used:

  - `-NoProfile` isn't strictly necessary, but advisable, because it suppresses loading of PowerShell's [profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), which can both help performance and makes for a predictable execution environment.
  - `-Command` isn't strictly necessary with [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, as it is the implied default; however, it *is* necessary if you call the [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) CLI, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), which now defaults to `-File` instead.
- The PowerShell code used to extract the links:

  - Since your script invokes an *external program*, `7z.exe`, that program's stdout is reported *line by line* by PowerShell.
  - When the regex-based [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator is given an *array* as its LHS operand, it acts as a *filter*. Therefore, only those lines that start with (`^`) string `https://` are returned.

Comment: Hi @mklement0 unfortunately I cannot find the answer to this, so I hope you can help me with it. How can I pass the arguments to the powershell script in this case? I don't understand how I can keep using the regex but pass values of variables I store. For example with a python variable such as `product_Version= "1.1.7.2"` the code should execute `script.ps1  1.1.7.2 -match '^https://'`.

Comment: @MBud, use string interpolation, such as with f-strings: `f"{product_Version} -match '^https://'"` If you need further help, please ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks mklement0, the new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205213/pass-value-from-python-script-to-powershell-via-popen unfortunately this solution won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should have all in `p_out` as string (so you should already have it in Python) and now you should use Python's functions to extract it from this string. You can split to lines and search line with `https` at the beginning. OR you can use regex.

```
p_out  = '''7-Zip 22.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2022 Igor Pavlov : 2022-07-15

Scanning the drive:
7 folders, 21 files, 21544 bytes (22 KiB)

Creating archive: conf.tar
Creating archive: conf2.tar

Removing tar file after upload...
Generating Links:
--------------------------------------------------------------
Link_1
https://some-repository.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/conf.tar?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
--------------------------------------------------------------
Link_2
https://some-repository.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/conf2.tar?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..'''

lines = p_out.split('\n')

links = []

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('http'):
        line = line.strip() # remove '\n' and spaces
        links.append(line)
        
for url in links:        
    print('url:', url)
```

Result:

```
url: https://some-repository.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/conf.tar?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
url: https://some-repository.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/conf2.tar?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
```

---

And if you don't have it in `p_out` then you should check if `p_err`.