# Pass value from Python script to Powershell via Popen

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, subprocess, popen

A bit of background, I just had a great answer on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73135462/python-3-10-script-calling-a-powershell-script-how-to-store-output-after-a-cer) that allowed me to progress with my project.
What I am working on is a Python script that calls a Powershell script.
I am extracting lines of the output of the python script while calling it as recommended in previous answer:

```
#PYTHON
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
  ['powershell', '-NoProfile', '-Command', "(./script.ps1) -match '^https://'" ], 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True
)

# Wait for the process to terminate and collect its stdout and stderr output.
p_out, p_err = p.communicate()

# Split the single multi-line string that contains the links
# into individual lines.
lines = p_out.splitlines()

print(lines)
```

What I would like to do is to pass certain values produced by the python script to the powershell script.
For example, the powershell script as it is now, requests a value from the user on the prompt as follows:

```
#POWERSHELL
$VERSION = Read-Host "Enter the version number (e.g. 1.6.7.3)"
```

Can someone help me understand if it is possible to pass $VERSION from the python script via the Popen call?
I assume I need modification on both the python and Powershell scripts to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit for clarification: I am trying to pass a paramenter after the script and before the -match regex, but if I remove the parentheses around the file name the match will not be considered, i.e. the output will be the whole output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the response to the `Read-Host` prompt inside the `.ps1` PowerShellScript via *stdin*, which means providing it via the `p.communicate()` call:

```py
version="1.6.7.3"

# ...

p_out, p_err = p.communicate(input = f"{version}\n")
```