# popen comamnd is not working '<Popen: returncode: None args: ['powershell', ' .\\Powershell\\...>

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I am trying to run powershell script (which is working independently) from a python script.

I am using the below command to get the result first.

```
import subprocess,sys, json
cmd = " .\Powershell\file.ps1 "
result = subprocess.Popen(['pwsh', cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result)
```

But getting the error:

```
Popen: returncode: None args: ['powershell', ' .\\Powershell\\file...>
```

I tried using both "pwsh" and "powershell". Adding the complete path of pwsh.exe and powershell. Still getting same error.

What could be wrong when same code is working in other system? I have the powershell version installed correctly and the pwsh command is working in the system.

Comment: That's not an error. It's the representation of the `Popen` object.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73138973/45375) for an example of how to work with the object returned from `subprocess.Popen()`